# URL did not redirect when url is in the text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did the error message when user did not upload the file. But when I submit the button, it did not redirect based on the url in the text input. It keeps on looping on `Please  upload a file`.I'm not sure what went wrong. It should be when user did not upload a file, it will prompt the user to upload QR image and the url will be decoded in the url. The `Submit button` will redirect the url located in the text input.

Comment: Hey @Ivana Mica, why the function referred in onclick is different than the one specified in Javascript - windowLocate vs windowLocation

Comment: @CuriousMind i just edited it

Comment: Hey @Ivana Mica, need more details like the environment you are using to execute this code etc. Can you create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) , it will help to identify and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers block new windows, and even new tabs from being opened by javascript as an attempt to prevent web developers from creating endless popups everywhere (think 1990's Mountain Dew ads).

Actually... Javascript CAN do those things, but only if it happens *immediately after user click*, or some other user interaction. If you delay the action from happening, then the browser thinks you're doing a popup and blocks it. You can get permission to show popups, but users never agree to that, so it's a waste of time.

So you have a few options:

**Redirect, or open new tab/window immediately!** Javascript can open new tabs and windows if it's a direct result of user's interaction with web page

```
function windowLocate(){
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length != 0) {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        window.open(url);
    } else {
        alert('Choose a file please');
    }
}
```

**Show a confirmation dialog.** If you have to show a message before redirecting, a confirmation modal would work.

```
function windowLocate(){
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length != 0) {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        var confirmed = confirm("You will now be redirected. Click below to confirm.")
        if (confirmed === true){
            window.open(url);
        }
    } else {
        alert('Choose a file please');
    }
}
```

**Redirect the current page!** If the user can stay on the same page, you can just redirect the page you're currently on, no problem!

```
function windowLocate(){
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length != 0) {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        window.location.assign(url);
    } else {
        alert('Choose a file please');
    }
}
```